# change the default version of python in kali linux

Tags: python, python-3.x

[tried to install sherlock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQO5I.png) 
for installing sherlock python 3.6 or more required, i installed python 3.8.2.But the default version is not changed it remain as python 2.7.17.

Comment: i suggest using `pyenv`, which will help you with installing/managing python versions, as well as virtual environments.

Answer (score 3):

Here is [a link that may help](https://exitcode0.net/kali-linux-how-to-upgrade-python-2-7-to-python-3-7/). Check it out! 
Basically:

1. Check your existing python version by running:

   python -V

   or

   python --version
2. List all the available items by running:

   ls /usr/bin/python
3. Now, set your version priorities by issuing the following commands:

   update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2.7 1

   update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.8 2
4. You can then list the python priorities by:

   update-alternatives --config python
5. Finally, check your default python version to confirm by repeating the first step!

I have included a screenshot of the same. Check it out. 
[Change Default Python Version Priority.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gv1l.png)

Answer (score 1):

Just taking the needed part from @George Oyosa's answer

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.8 2
```

Just execute it and the the command **update-alternatives** will handle the rest for you.

Answer (score 0):

Simply open terminal and run "alias python=python3" (without the quotes) then run "python -V" to check

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt install -y python-is-python3
```

As explain here : [Everything you need to know about the switch to Python 3](https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/python3-transition/)